# Same GetHashCode() for different objects

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

After executing this piece of code:

```
int a = 50;
float b = 50.0f;
Console.WriteLine(a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode());
```

We get `False`, which is expected, since we are dealing with different objects, hence we should get different hashes.

However, if we execute this:

```
int a = 0;
float b = 0.0f;
Console.WriteLine(a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode());
```

We get `True`. Both obejcts return the same hash code: `0`.

Why does this happen? Aren't they supposed to return different hashes?

Comment: not nessaraly - they are only ints.

Comment: have a look here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs#2d2b91f1bdc71dbb#references and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs#73ee1ece33d0d0e6#references

Comment: If we check equality `a.Equals(b)`, we get `False`, even if their hashes are the same

Comment: hashes are one way to group items together, not verify uniqueness.

Comment: Your misconception is that different or non-equal objects should have different hash codes.  The only requirement of a hash code is that equal objects have the same hash code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GetHashCode` of `System.Int32` works like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this;
}
```

Which of course with this being `0`, it will return `0`.

`System.Single`'s (`float` is alias) `GetHashCode` is:

```
public unsafe override int GetHashCode()
{
    float num = this;
    if (num == 0f)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return *(int*)(&num);
}
```

Like you see, at `0f` it will return `0`.

Program used is ILSpy.

Comment: I guess this explains everything :)

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However,
>   the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object
>   equality, because different (unequal) objects can have identical hash
>   codes.

Answer (score 1):

Objects that are conceptually equal are obligated to return the same hashes.  Objects that are different are **not** obligated to return different hashes.  That would only be possible if there were less than 2^32 objects that could ever possibly exist.  There are more than that.  When objects that are different result in the same hash it is called a "collision".  A quality hash algorithm minimizes collisions as much as possible, but they can never be removed entirely.

Comment: Didn't know that fact!

Comment: Shouldn't your fist sentence be "Objects that are conceptually equal are obligated to return the **same** hashes"?

Answer (score 0):

Why should they? Hash codes are a finite set; as many as you can fit in an `Int32`. There are many many doubles that will have the same hash code as any given int or any other given double.

Hash codes basically have to follow two simple rules:

1. If two objects are equal, they should have the same hash code.
2. If an object does not mutate its internal state then the hash code should remain the same.

Nothing obliges two objects that are not equal to have different hash codes; it is mathematically impossible.