# I printed hashcode for both A & B and I got the same address. Both object gets created side by side in memory. But how come with same address?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public class A 
{
    public A()
    {
     Console.WriteLine(this.GetHashCode());
     Console.WriteLine("A Created");
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
     Console.WriteLine(this.GetHashCode());
     Console.WriteLine("B Created");
    }
}
public class C
{
  public static void Main(String[] args)
  {
      B t = new B();
  }
}
```

Output:
1805487208
A Created
1805487208
B Created

Why i got the same address for these 2 objects. Actually these 2 objects must be created side by side . But how come we are getting the same address for these two objects???

Comment: There is only one object (B includes A; it is not *separate* from A). Why do you think there are two?

Comment: BTW, this question could be duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615241/2265446

Comment: @MatthewWatson ty, deleting the comment to avoid confusion

Comment: There are two objects getting created..one for class A, and other for class B(INTERNALLY).

Comment: @SakethKota No, there are NOT two objects being created. Only ONE object is created - the B object, which extends the A class.

Comment: *"Actually these 2 objects must be created side by side"* - why do you think that? And why do you think that there are two objects at all?

Comment: @MatthewWatson  Two objects are created and there is no doubt in that..Ok lemme send you a code to prove that for your clarity...i have created destructors for the two classes..when the objects scope is finished the destructors are called before respective objects get deleted.  THIS MEANS AN OBJECT GETTING CREATED AND GETTING DESTROYED

Comment: using System;
public class A {
    String s="saketh";
public A(){
        // Console.WriteLine(this.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode());
 Console.WriteLine("A Created");
 }
    ~A(){
        Console.WriteLine("A Deleted");
    }
}
public class B : A
    {
    public B(){
        //  Console.WriteLine(this.GetHashCode());
 Console.WriteLine("B Created");
 }
    ~B(){
        Console.WriteLine("B Deleted");
    }
}
public class C
{
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
           B t = new B();
    }
}

Comment: @SakethKota, maybe you should read up on inheritance

Comment: On a side node, why did the constructor of parent class gets invoked without calling super()? is this something unique to C#?

Comment: @SakethKota Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172738/c-net-inheritance-number-of-objects-created-in-memory

Comment: @Mox C++ also does this. If there is ONLY a parameterless constructor for a base class, it will be called automatically when you construct an instance of a derived class. If there is more than one constructor, you must choose which one to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same GetHashCode() for different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615134/same-gethashcode-for-different-objects)

Comment: @ABAbhi That's a different issue. There aren't two objects, there is only one object.

Comment: What do you mean by "addresses"? Where did you check that any of these objects has an "address"?

Comment: The .Net Source Code is available, but as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196724/2557128), addresses have nothing to do with hashcodes, and having the default `Object.GetHashCode` return the same value means you have the same object.